# Creating a selector in a an .each() loop using class and data attribute

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the value of three fields (input, select, and textarea) on a page.  I'm using jQuery to hide and show multiple tabs with the same fields on each section.

Disclaimer: I'm using the word object below loosely.  I'm not 100% sure I understand the entire concept, but I think I sort of get it.

I've tried the following in the console and it returns an object with the specific fields I want in them (I know the correct object is being returned because I have another "data-line" attribute that has an matching id number to the section I'm showing).

```
$(".checkFields:visible").each(function() {
  var test = $(this);
  console.log(test);
});
```

So, I thought the below would then get me closer to the value, but it returns the exact same object:

```
$(".checkFields:visible").each(function() {
  var test = $(this).attr("data-field").val();
  console.log(test);
});
```

I've also tried the below in attempt to pluck them out one by one with no luck.

```
var test = $('.checkFields:visible[data-field="operation"]');
console.log(test);
```

I'm not 100% sure on what should be included in the initial object, but this seems correct to me (what shoes up in console when running the first two queries.

```
Object 
{ 0: input.checkFields.form-control, 1: select.checkFields.form-control, 2: textarea.checkFields.form-control, length: 3, prevObject: {…}, context: HTMLDocument http://myWebsite/myWebpage.php?id=29001, selector: ".checkFields:visible"}
```

How can I return the value of a field that that has my class, is visible, with my specified data-field value?

Comment: You don't need `.attr("data-field").val()`. If you want the value of an `<input>`, `<textarea>`, or `<select>`, just do `.val()`. If you're trying to access an attribute of these elements (like `<input data-field="Hello world">`), then `.attr("data-field")`, or `.data("field")`, would return `"Hello world"`. Your last test didn't work because you can't change what gets returned via a selector - you're simply telling jQuery "Hey, go find me any elements that satisfy *this* selector", and so the return will *always* be that: an element, or list of elements.

Comment: use `$('.checkFields:visible[data-field="operation"]').each.....` then inside of it use `$(this).val()`

Comment: Both of these worked guys.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, the below worked:

```
var value = $('.checkFields:visible[data-field="operation"]').val();
console.log(value);
```

Returns my value = 'asdf'

```
$('.checkFields:visible[data-field]').each(function() {
    field = $(this).data("field");
    value = $(this).val();
    console.log(field+": "+test);
});
```

Returns all of my values.
operation: adsfsda
workCenter: adsfsda
operationNotes: adsfsda

I feel like I tried these for sure but I guess not.  Long day I suppose.